# How to change row indexes on QTableWidget on PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

So i have a Table which looks something like this:

[image]

and I want to change the indexes circled in red.
How do I do that?

Comment: [`setVerticalHeaderLabels()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setVerticalHeaderLabels) or [`setVerticalHeaderItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setVerticalHeaderItem)

Comment: Thanks. that is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

as `musicamante` said in the comments, the answer is using the methods:

```py
setVerticalHeaderLabels()
or
setVerticalHeaderItem()
```